# Invalid depfile: Flutter (Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build:)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           10.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[88351]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x20aa5b678) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1083b82c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[88351]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x20aa5b6c8) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1083b8318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Invalid depfile: /Users/akshaydeshpande/StudioProjects/My Budget/.dart_tool/flutter_build/21e2694a07dda4dc41836ce71056be61/kernel_snapshot.d
    Invalid depfile: /Users/akshaydeshpande/StudioProjects/My Budget/.dart_tool/flutter_build/21e2694a07dda4dc41836ce71056be61/kernel_snapshot.d
    Invalid depfile: /Users/akshaydeshpande/StudioProjects/My Budget/.dart_tool/flutter_build/21e2694a07dda4dc41836ce71056be61/kernel_snapshot.d
    Invalid depfile: /Users/akshaydeshpande/StudioProjects/My Budget/.dart_tool/flutter_build/21e2694a07dda4dc41836ce71056be61/kernel_snapshot.d
    Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'money_tracker' in 'package:money_tracker/HomeWidget.dart'.
    Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'money_tracker' in 'package:money_tracker/SplashWidget.dart'.
    lib/main.dart:4:8: Error: Not found: 'package:money_tracker/HomeWidget.dart'
    import 'package:money_tracker/HomeWidget.dart';
           ^
    lib/main.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'package:money_tracker/SplashWidget.dart'
    import 'package:money_tracker/SplashWidget.dart';
           ^
    lib/main.dart:22:50: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'HomeWidget'.
              '/home': (BuildContext context) => new HomeWidget(parentCtx: context),
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^
    lib/main.dart:23:52: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'SplashWidget'.
              '/splash': (BuildContext context) => new SplashWidget(),
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Unhandled exception:
    FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:package%3Amoney_tracker%2FHomeWidget.dart; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
    #0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
    #1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:614:37)
    #2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:754:21)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:571:9)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #4      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:85:12)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #5      main (file:///opt/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:13:24)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    Failed to package /Users/akshaydeshpande/StudioProjects/My Budget.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

Comment: Please share your HomeWidget class as it seems that a lot of errors originate from it. Go over the errors listed here and find their origin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have resolved it.